# Query returns back empty even though data is in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using CI to do a call to a database like so:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
->from('dr_template_relational')
->where('value_id', $categoryDetails['value_id'])
 ->where('subcategory_id', $categoryDetails['subcategory_id'])
->where('categories_id', $categoryDetails['categories_id'])
->get();
```

I then check if the data exists in the database.  If the data is not there I'd like to insert it if it is there I'd like to skip it.

```
                        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
                        echo 'it exists';
                                echo $categoryDetails['value_id'];
                    }
                    else{
                                echo 'it DOES NOT';
                                echo $categoryDetails['value_id'];
                        $this->db->insert('dr_template_relational', $categoryDetails);
                    }
```

I get it DOES NOT and the category detail but I'm sure this is in the database.
As shown below the data is present yet it still runs the else.  Any idea why and how I can resolve this?  Simply put if the data is in the database I shouldn't write to it.

```
246641  7810    245 0   NULL    RS_RS_245_1 21
246656  7810    245 0   NULL    RS_RS_245_1 21
246657  7810    245 0   NULL    RS_RS_245_1 21
246658  7810    245 0   NULL    RS_RS_245_1 21
246659  7810    245 0   NULL    RS_RS_245_1 21
246660  7810    245 0   NULL    RS_RS_245_1 21
246661  7810    245 0   NULL    RS_RS_245_1 21
```

Comment: Do you want `subcategory id = ? AND categories_id = ?` or do you want `subcategory_id =? OR categories_id = ?`?

Comment: I suggest you use `$query->getQuery()` to see the final query after all the builder logic is done, then examine that query to make sure it looks like what you want. Then test that query in the mysql client to make sure it work the way you expect.

Comment: CI has a useful function for this situation to get your debugging rolling: `echo $this->db->last_query();` use the generated query in your phpAdmin or other mysql client and see if you get results...

Comment: besides this problem, once solved (right now your query doesn't return a row, so the query is wrong or the data queried doesn't exist), you should have a look at the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). That might give you some more ideas on how to handle insert versus update

Comment: AND @BillKarwin

Comment: ok I will, thank you @Vickel

Comment: That worked Bill, thank you so much it helped me to diagnose the issue, your'e awesome!  @BillKarwin

Comment: Why don’t you just use $this->db->query(“SELECT * FROM.....”);